# Close reasons should be updated to reflect Meta, not Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, off-topic

This *might* be worked on soon (or I may be preempting it), but this feels wrong.

[image]

Shouldn't it read something* like this:

> **Programming questions** are off-topic on Meta.  Please refer to "How to Ask".  See also:  Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?

<sup>*Some wordsmithing required</sup>

Comment: Programming questions are probably not going to be as big of a problem anymore either, so it might be best to see if replacing it completely would be a better idea.

Comment: No, I'm willing to bet that programming questions would still get asked here.  At least, in the beginning.

Comment: Very sneaky, Shog.  I see what you did there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're crazy. That off-topic reason doesn't exist here. I'm pretty sure you faked that screenshot, you big phony!

Comment: Well, the team seems to move quicker at squashing those bugs than I do at posting 'em.  Well played.

Comment: *upvotes only because of @Shog9's edit*